# How to add an additional array item to a computed observable at runtime

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, computed-observable

I am trying to append an additional value to a knockout computed observable with no luck. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.
Currently I am iterating through a collection of fields and building an array of dates

```
//extract Primary dates from entities
report.PrimaryDateRangeAttributes = ko.computed(function () {
      return $.grep(entity.PrimaryAttributes(), function (item) { return item.DataType() === 'datetime' });
 });
```

Once I get the array built I wanted to add one additional item

```
report.PrimaryDateRangeAttributes.push('DateEntered');
```

However push is not supported on a computed observable. Can anyone provide some suggestions on how to insert the additional value during the initialization of the object?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why don't use use an observableArray? Then push works perfectly. Your scenario doesn't seem to provide any reason as to why you wouldn't.

Comment: @beauXjames Using grep to return the items in the object would never populate the observable array when I attempted. I assumed a computed observable must be the only manner to accomplish this simply writing something like var myarray = ko.observableArray($.grep(entity..... would never populate.

Comment: just do ko.observableArray($.grep(...));
in short, remove the initial function(), for it was just a function, not an array.

Comment: You can also run with ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(entitiy.PrimaryAttributes(), function(item) { return ...condition for true... }))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the computation function is called to build the value whenever the value is required (that's the purpose of `computed`, after all), you simply add that within the function:

```
//extract Primary dates from entities
report.PrimaryDateRangeAttributes = ko.computed(function () {
      var rv = $.grep(entity.PrimaryAttributes(), function (item) { return item.DataType() === 'datetime' });
      rv.push('DateEntered');
      return rv;
});
```